# При вызове nativeEvent lParam == NULL

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb

В инклюде описываю `nativeevent`, в майнвиндоу реализую `nativeevent`, в конструкторе майнвиндоу подписываю на сообщения. `hDevNotyfy not NULL`, но при этом, что с регистрацией, что без, ивент происходит при всех `WM_DEVICECHANGE`

При отладке видно, что `lParam == 0` Ниже код:

```
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter ; 
ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter)) ; 
NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE); 
NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE; 
NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid; // {fb1cf0c4-b412-451f-9f04-df7537a5003c}
hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter,DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
//
LRESULT __stdcall WindowHandler(HWND hWnd, DWORD uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
 switch (uMsg){
   case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
      if (lParam==0) {};// Тут ноль
      break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Читайте описание https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, lParam не обязательно должен быть не ноль.

Comment: Msdn говорит что при подписке на devtype interface lparam всегда указатель на dev broadcast

Comment: Уже нашел спасибо. Но остается первая половина вопроса, почему не работает подписка?

Comment: Registerdevicenotification

Comment: `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter ;`  
`ZeroMemory(&NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter)) ;`  
`NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);`  
`NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;`  
`NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = InterfaceClassGuid;`  
    `hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);`  Где InterfaceClassGuid  класс моего устройства

Comment: {fb1cf0c4-b412-451f-9f04-df7537a5003c} разве вопрос похож на монитор флэшки?

Comment: А чему у вас равно wParam? Может вам нужно поставить условие что `if (wParam==DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC/*0x8005*/)`
`

Comment: нет, от устройства приходит только devnode change

Comment: Ещёраз повторюсь для DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED lParam=0 https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx "The system broadcasts the DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED device event when a device has been added to or removed from the system. Applications that maintain lists of devices in the system should refresh their lists." Система посылает сообщение для того что бы приложение обновила списки своих устройств. Всё, никаких доп-параметров это сообщение не передаёт. Если вам нужно что-то другое - уточните вопрос.

Comment: ...Registerdevicenotification ! либо мс умалчивает в описании этой функции что то, либо либо, я так понимаю что данная регистрация должна определить фильтр по гуайди на уровне оси и приложение не должно получить срабатывание ивента по "чужому" гуайди, иное должно быть гдето описано - я не нашел.

Comment: Вы обьясните, что вы хотите увидеть на **выходе**.  Какая именно информация вам нужна. Список чего? Список usb-устройтств?  Список устройств определённого типа? В таком виде вы получаете имеено то что предполагала Microsoft - сигнал о том что появились или ушли устройства.

Comment: wmdevicechange ивент оси, когда я на него подписываюсь что происходит? зачемуказывать класс гуайди который ни на что не влияет?

Comment: Скажу иначе, я давно уже сделал через перечисление, и убрал подписку, все работает, но ивент "хлопает" на каждый месседж рассылаемый системой, склоняюсь к багу кьюта.

Comment: Может вам http://microsin.net/programming/pc/ftdi-usb-device-event-in-windows.html поможет?

Comment: Издеваетесь? У моего логгера-маппера два интерфейса, один из них на фтди, другой j2534 в чистом виде, openport 1.3 и openport 2.0, портянку из пдф фтди (микрозин что вы привели это перевод) я использовал в первую очередь. С фтди думаю все отл ( не реализовывал ещё эту ветвь), а вот оп2.0 от тактрикс беда,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в правильной подписке на сообщения это хэндл окна, при определении хэндла как (HWND)this->winId() где this - MainWindow, тогда при использовании nativeEvent все работает.